# Restricting the area of text that is searched by python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib

I am wanting to search and count the number of times a string comes up in a webscrape. However I want to search between x and y within the webscrape.

Can anyone tell me the easiest method to count SEA BASS between MAIN FISHERMAN and SECONDARY FISHERMAN in the following example webscrape.

```
<p style="color: #555555;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;">June 21, 2013  By FISH PPL Admin  </small>

</div>
<!-- Post Body Copy -->

<div class="post-bodycopy clearfix"><p>MAIN FISHERMAN &#8211; </p>
<p><strong>CHAMP</strong> &#8211; Pedro 00777<br />
BAIT &#8211; LOCATION1 &#8211; 2:30 &#8211; SEA BASS (3 LBS 11/4)<br />
MULTI – LOCATION2 &#8211; 7:30 &#8211; COD (3 LBS 13/8)<br />
LURE – LOCATION5 &#8211; 3:20 &#8211; RUDD (2 LBS 6/1)</p>
<p>JOE BLOGGS <a href="url">url</a><br />
BAIT &#8211; LOCATION4 &#8211; 4:45 &#8211; ROACH (5 LBS 3/1)<br />
MULTI – LOCATION2 &#8211; 5:50 &#8211; PERCH (3 LBS 6/1)<br />
LURE – LOCATION1 &#8211; 3:45 &#8211; PIKE (2 LBS 5/1) </p>
BAIT &#8211; LOCATION1 &#8211; 2:30 &#8211; SEA BASS (3 LBS 11/4)<br />
MULTI – LOCATION1 &#8211; 3:45 &#8211; JUST THE JUDGE (3 LBS 3/1)<br />
LURE – LOCATION3 &#8211; 8:25 &#8211; SCHOOL FEES (2 LBS 7/1)</p>
<div class="post-bodycopy clearfix"><p>SECONDARY FISHERMAN &#8211; </p>
<p><strong>SPOON &#8211; <a href="url">url</a></strong><br />
BAIT &#8211; LOCATION1 &#8211; 2:30 &#8211; SEA BASS (3 LBS 11/4)<br />
MULTI – LOCATION2 &#8211; 7:30 &#8211; COD (3 LBS 7/4)<br />
LURE – LOCATION1 &#8211; 4:25 &#8211; TROUT (2 LBS 5/1)</p>
```

I attempted to use the following code to achieve this, but to no avail.

```
html = website.read()

pattern_to_exclude_unwanted_data = re.compile('MAIN FISHERMAN(.*)SECONDARY FISHERMAN')

excluding_unwanted_data = re.findall(pattern_to_exclude_unwanted_data, html)

print excluding_unwanted_data("SEA BASS")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

1. Extract the substring between MAIN FISHERMAN and SECONDARY FISHERMAN.
2. Count SEA BASS

Like this:

```
relevant = re.search(r"MAIN FISHERMAN(.*)SECONDARY FISHERMAN", html, re.DOTALL).group(1)
found = relevant.count("SEA BASS")
```

Comment: Oops, yes I didn't think about DOTALL-- and the `group` thing was just sloppy, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `'MAIN FISHERMAN'` and `'SECONDARY FISHERMAN'` as markers to find `<div>` elements to count `'SEA BASS'` within:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
inbetween = False
count = 0
for div in soup.find_all('div', ["post-bodycopy", "clearfix"]):
    if not inbetween:
       inbetween = div.find(text=re.compile('MAIN FISHERMAN')) # check start
    else: # inbetween
       inbetween = not div.find(text=re.compile('SECONDARY FISHERMAN')) # end
    if inbetween:
       count += len(div.find_all(text=re.compile('SEA BASS')))

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code (untested):

```
count = 0
enabled = false
for line in file:
  if 'MAIN FISHERMAN' in line:
    enabled = true
  elif enabled and 'SEA BASS' in line:
    count += 1
  elif 'SECONDARY FISHERMAN' in line:
    enabled = false
```